# Why do I always get "Returned values are not valid, did it run Out of Gas"?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm new on Ethereum blockchain and I'm working on deploy and using smart contracts using truffle on my private blockchain.

I have followed exactly this guide 
 https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts

But every time i call *getBalance()* function

```
   -> truffle(develop)> let balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[0])
   -> truffle(develop)> balance.toNumber()
```

**I get the error**: 
Returned values are not valid, did it run Out of Gas

So I added a simple smart contract *getNumber()* then return a simply integer (3) and I always get the same error.

But if I invoke *sendCoin()* function  I don't get any error and I write correctly the transaction.

So I get the error any time I try to get values from the blockchain.

Someone can help me?

Comment: did you try just balance. get function did not consume gas. gas is used when we add new data to block chain.

Comment: Are using Ganache? What is your version?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you did not deploy your contract properly. Interacting with a not exist or wrong contract could lead to that error message.

In truffle develop, try `migrate` command to compile and deploy your contracts and then see if it can work.